# php DOMDocument levels

Tags: php, xml, dom

```
<?php

// include db config 
require("config.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$node = $dom->createElement("path");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Select all the rows in the link table
$query = "select * from mytable";
        
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  $node = $dom->createElement("link");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['siteName']); 
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['latitude']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['longitude']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Code above generates xml

```
<path>
    <link name="howard" lat="54.36603" lng="-8.51472"/>
    <link name="ramesh" lat="53.8458" lng="-8.3919"/>
    <link name="paula" lat="54.84487" lng="-8.87309"/>
    <link name="rita" lat="51.43692" lng="-9.42123"/>
</path>
```

How can I add one more level to the xml to generate xml below?

```
<paths>
    <path>
        <link name="howard" lat="54.36603" lng="-8.51472"/>
        <link name="ramesh" lat="53.8458" lng="-8.3919"/>
        <link name="paula" lat="54.84487" lng="-8.87309"/>
        <link name="rita" lat="51.43692" lng="-9.42123"/>
    </path>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right :-)
it's late

now works

```
        <?php
    
    // include db config 
    require("config.php"); 
   
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$node_root = $dom->createElement("paths");
$pathadd = $dom->appendChild($node_root);

$node2 = $dom->createElement("path");
$parnode = $pathadd->appendChild($node2);
    
    // Select all the rows in the link table
    $query = "select * from mytable";
            
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    
    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    
      $node = $dom->createElement("link");
      $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
      $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['siteName']); 
      $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['latitude']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['longitude']);
    }
    
    echo $dom->saveXML();
    ?>
```

Comment: your solution produces only one level

Comment: you are right :-) it's late

now workslook now

Comment: nice one! Thanks